# EF6 Query Plan Caching

Tags: c#, performance, caching, entity-framework-6

Query Plan Caching

> The first time a query is executed, it goes through the internal plan
>   compiler to translate the conceptual query into the store command
>   (e.g. the T-SQL which is executed when run against SQL Server). If
>   query plan caching is enabled, the next time the query is executed the
>   store command is retrieved directly from the query plan cache for
>   execution, bypassing the plan compiler.
>
> The query plan cache is shared across ObjectContext instances within
>   the same AppDomain. You don't need to hold onto an ObjectContext
>   instance to benefit from query plan caching.

I am using EF6 and have a TPT mapping table and the first time I try to access data from it takes 8 to 10 Sec.  But consecutive call after that just takes milliseconds. My understanding is EF store query execution plan.

1)  It takes 5 Sec when the execution plan is not cached in EF.
2)  And it takes less than 10 milliseconds when the execution plan is cached.

My question is there any way to manually add execution plan to EF.

I have seen ways to generate a pre-compile view (using generating Mapping Views with the EF Power Tools), so I was wondering if there is a way to add known execution plan to EF when it application start up.

Comment: A cached execution plan would not turn your queries from milliseconds to 10 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, David, for your reply,
Can you please try to elaborate your comment, and explain more about it.

I might be wrong, but my observation is EF generated complex queries for TPT hierarchies probably about 2000 lines big, is there is a way to attach a sample project and explain to you if you can answer my question, it would be a great help.
More details can be found here.
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2332

Comment: Query plans are in the database, not EF. Are you confusing them with the model store or the local query views?

Comment: I am new to EF I might be wrong,
 But I was trying to follow the guidelines from MSDN on Performance Considerations for EF 4, 5, and 6
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/hh949853.aspx  and 

Section 3.2 Query Plan Caching
Talk more about query plan Caching, I might have understood wrong, so you mean EF will not cache the query for future use.

Comment: A query plan is something that the database creates when you send it a SQL statement. You may get some mileage out of [this](https://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/3-steps-for-fast-entityframework-6.1-code-first-startup-performance/) though

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right direction,
I did get better startup time by trying 2 of the options suggested by David Roth
2. Generate pre-compiled views
And 
3. Generate pre-compiled version of entityframework using on-going to avoid getting
But never tried the first one will see if it fixed my problem.
Thanks once again.

Comment: EF does have query plans as well. Section 3.2 "Query Plan Caching" in the article mentioned by @sam above refers to the EF cache.